# Specify separator character in "separate" function from package tidyr

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I have a tibble with a column containing strings in the format XX_YY_ZZ. I need to separate the column into *two* different columns using the *first* underscore as a separation character.

The function tidyr::separate will match both underscores and discard the piece of string after the second one. Googling around I've found the regex "*(?!.**)" that matches only the last underscore, but I've not been able to find one matching only the first one.

My data look like:

```
d <- tibble(var = paste0(LETTERS[1:5], "_", 1:5, "_", letters[1:5])) 
d %>% separate(var, into=c("newcol1", "newcol2"))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  newcol1 newcol2
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 A       1      
2 B       2      
3 C       3      
4 D       4      
5 E       5      
Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 5 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
```

What I need to have is:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  newcol1 newcol2
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 A       1_a
2 B       2_b
3 C       3_c
4 D       4_d
5 E       5_e
```

Comment: Can your strings have more than 2 underscores? Or no underscores? Try `d %>% extract(var, into=c("newcol1", "newcol2"), "([^_]*)_(.*)")`

Comment: or split into three cols then `unite` the last two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to solve the problem.

```
d %>% separate(var, into = c("newcol1", "newcol2"), sep = "_(?=.*_)")
```

Here, the regex `_(?=.*_)` means: `_` followed by a string including another `_`.

The result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  newcol1 newcol2
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 A       1_a    
2 B       2_b    
3 C       3_c    
4 D       4_d    
5 E       5_e
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Specify `extra = "merge"`

```
d %>% 
  separate(var, into=c("newcol1", "newcol2"), extra = "merge", sep = "_")
```

**2)** or replace the first underscore with two underscores and then split on that.

```
d %>% 
  mutate(var = sub("_", "__", var)) %>% 
  separate(var, into=c("newcol1", "newcol2"), sep = "__")
```

**3)** or just use `mutate` and `sub` instead of `separate`:

```
d %>%
  mutate(newcol1 = sub("_.*", "", var), newcol2 = sub(".*?_", "", var), var = NULL)
```